# SQL Table Variable issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I declare a table variable as `APTDAPCO` is a user defined type

```
DECLARE @APTDAPCO APTDAPCO

INSERT INTO @APTDAPCO
    SELECT 
        APTD.APCo, 
        APTD.Mth,
        APTD.APTrans,
        APTD.APLine,
        APTD.Amount, 
        APTD.PayType, 
        APTD.PaidDate,
        APCO.RetPayType
    FROM
        [Viewpoint].[dbo].[APTD] WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN 
        [Viewpoint].[dbo].[APCO] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [APCO].[APCo] = [APTD].[APCo]
    WHERE 
        APTD.APCo = 1
```

This is in one stored procedure.

When I try to use this table variable in a select statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM HQCO 
LEFT JOIN @APTDAPCO ON HQCO.CO = @APTDAPCO.APCo
```

I keep getting a compilation error in my stored procedure

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure lc_PM11127_CommitmentReport_Optimize, Line 80 [Batch Start Line 9]
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@APTDAPCO".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run them both in the same sproc or in the same query window in one execution. Does it work?

Comment: You have to declare the variable as a table - see below

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @APTDAPCO table
(APCO varchar(max), mth varchar(max), 
Aptrans varchar(max), apline varchar(max),
Amount  float, paytype varchar(max),
Paiddate datetime, retpaytype varchar(max))
Insert into @APTDAPCO
    Select APTD.APCo, 
    APTD.Mth,
    APTD.APTrans,
    APTD.APLine,
    APTD.Amount, 
    APTD.PayType, 
    APTD.PaidDate,
    APCO.RetPayType
    from [Viewpoint].[dbo].[APTD] WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN [Viewpoint].[dbo].[APCO] WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON [APCO].[APCo] = [APTD].[APCo]
    Where APTD.APCo=1
```

Comment: I did this now I get Incorrect syntax near insert expecting (

Comment: Yes you have to define the table and field types - I’ll adjust code